# How to actively display the stats on an HTML document each time a for loop updates the values?

Tags: javascript, html

Disclaimer: Extremely newbie with HTML and javascript. Also, sorry about the formatting, I'm accustomed to lua.

I'm trying to make it so that each time the for loop repeats and pulls up the prompt, it actively updates and *displays* the stats on the HTML document.

Stats referring to:

- the total damage after the user inputs the amount of attacks they want to do
- the total damage the dragon does to the user
- the health of the dragon after the user attack was completed
- the health of the user after the dragon attack was completed

Also, I'm having an issue where when either the dragon or user wins, the health stats that are displayed is the health before the last attack was made.

Any help at all is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
var userDmg = document.body.querySelector(".userDamage")
var dragDmg = document.body.querySelector(".dragonDamage")

var userHthTotal = document.body.querySelector(".userHealth")
var dragHthTotal = document.body.querySelector(".dragonHealth")

var userOut = document.body.querySelector(".userOutcome")
var dragOut = document.body.querySelector(".dragonOutcome")



for (var userHealth = 50, dragHealth = 100; userHealth > 0 && dragHealth > 0;)

  {

var userInput = Number(prompt("A dragon has appeared! How many hits do you want to deal?"))    

userHthTotal.innerHTML = "Your health: " +userHealth
dragHthTotal.innerHTML = "Dragon's health: " +dragHealth

if(userInput > 5)
  {userOut.innerHTML = "You exhausted yourself and died."
  userHealth = 0}
else if(userInput <= 0)
  {userOut.innerHTML = "The dragon was disappointed with your non-exstant attack. You died."
  userHealth = 0}
else if(userInput === 5)
  {userDmg.innerHTML = "Your attacks were weak. You deal 1 damage."
  dragDmg.innerHTML = "The dragon is able to land a critical hit and deals 20 damage."
  dragHealth = dragHealth - 1
  userHealth = userHealth - 20}
else if(userInput === 1 || userInput === 2 || userInput === 3 || userInput === 4)
  {var userAttackDmg = Number(userInput) * (Math.floor(Math.random() * 20))
  userDmg.innerHTML = "You dealt " +userAttackDmg+ " damage!"
  dragHealth = dragHealth - userAttackDmg
  
  var dragAttackDmg = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 10
  dragDmg.innerHTML = "The dragon dealt " +dragAttackDmg+ " damage!"
  userHealth = userHealth - dragAttackDmg}
else
  {userOut.innerHTML = "You confused yourself. You died."
  userHealth = 0}

 if(userHealth < 0)
  {userOut.innerHTML = "Tough battle, but the dragon kills you."
  dragOut.innerHTML = "The dragon goes on to pay a visit to your village."}

if(dragHealth < 0)
  {userOut.innerHTML = "You are victorious!"
  dragOut.innerHTML = "However, watch out, the spirit of the dragon will probably haunt you for the rest of your life."}
    
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to move your statupdate (these 2 lines:)

```
userHthTotal.innerHTML = "Your health: " +userHealth
dragHthTotal.innerHTML = "Dragon's health: " +dragHealth
```

Below your big If-block, or even all the way to the bottom of your for loop.

Also, for your last 2 if-blocks i suspect you want to use `<=` instead of `<`

```
if (userHealth <= 0) ...

if (dragHealth <= 0) ...
```

---

Adjusted version:

```
var userDmg = document.body.querySelector(".userDamage")
var dragDmg = document.body.querySelector(".dragonDamage")

var userHthTotal = document.body.querySelector(".userHealth")
var dragHthTotal = document.body.querySelector(".dragonHealth")

var userOut = document.body.querySelector(".userOutcome")
var dragOut = document.body.querySelector(".dragonOutcome")



for (var userHealth = 50, dragHealth = 100; userHealth > 0 && dragHealth > 0;)

{

    var userInput = Number(prompt("A dragon has appeared! How many hits do you want to deal?"))


    if (userInput > 5) {
        userOut.innerHTML = "You exhausted yourself and died."
        userHealth = 0
    } else if (userInput <= 0) {
        userOut.innerHTML = "The dragon was disappointed with your non-exstant attack. You died."
        userHealth = 0
    } else if (userInput === 5) {
        userDmg.innerHTML = "Your attacks were weak. You deal 1 damage."
        dragDmg.innerHTML = "The dragon is able to land a critical hit and deals 20 damage."
        dragHealth = dragHealth - 1
        userHealth = userHealth - 20
    } else if (userInput === 1 || userInput === 2 || userInput === 3 || userInput === 4) {
        var userAttackDmg = Number(userInput) * (Math.floor(Math.random() * 20))
        userDmg.innerHTML = "You dealt " + userAttackDmg + " damage!"
        dragHealth = dragHealth - userAttackDmg

        var dragAttackDmg = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 10
        dragDmg.innerHTML = "The dragon dealt " + dragAttackDmg + " damage!"
        userHealth = userHealth - dragAttackDmg
    } else {
        userOut.innerHTML = "You confused yourself. You died."
        userHealth = 0
    }

    userHthTotal.innerHTML = "Your health: " + userHealth
    dragHthTotal.innerHTML = "Dragon's health: " + dragHealth

    if (userHealth <= 0) {
        userOut.innerHTML = "Tough battle, but the dragon kills you."
        dragOut.innerHTML = "The dragon goes on to pay a visit to your village."
    }

    if (dragHealth <= 0) {
        userOut.innerHTML = "You are victorious!"
        dragOut.innerHTML = "However, watch out, the spirit of the dragon will probably haunt you for the rest of your life."
    }

}
```